# fatal: bad boolean config value 'null' for 'commit.gpgsign' gitkraken and gitclients

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, gitkraken, git-gui

I am using `GitKraken` as my git client and it was always working fine, but for a few days I am getting the error `fatal: bad boolean config value 'null' for 'commit.gpgsign'` when I use any other git clients. I have tried `cmd`, `vscode`, `PowerShell` in `vscode` and `Git GUI`. I have also uninstalled the `GitKraken` and try, but I guess it somehow retains the settings. Have you ever experienced this issue?

Answer (score 13):

After scratching my head for a while, I found the solution for the same. You just have to go to your `.gitconfig` file in your user directory (C:\Users\SibeeshVenu) and remove the preceding settings.

```
[commit]
    gpgSign = null
```

In the end, this is how my `.gitconfig` looks like.

```
[user]
    email = myemail
    name = Sibeesh Venu
    signingKey = null
    password = mypassword
[core]
    longpaths = true
[gpg]
    program = null
[tag]
    forceSignAnnotated = null
[credential]
    helper = store
```

Comment: *All* of those `= null` entries appear damaged by some software (not sure what software). The `program` setting should be the path name of a program to run to invoke the GPG signer/checker; the `forceSignAnnotated` setting should be either `true` or `false`; and the `signingKey` should be absent, or set to some valid signing key (I'm not sure if this would be the key itself, or a path name, but `null` is definitely wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you have multiple profiles in GitKraken, especially if they existed prior to this setting. When you switch between them GitKraken updates the .gitconfig file from it's own internal settings for the profile, and if the profile does not have the `'commit.gpgsign'` setting then it writes it out as `'null'`.

The way to fix it is go through each of your GitKraken profiles and toggle the setting twice (first time to create the setting in the profile, and the second time to set the value back to it's original state). Now when you switch between profiles your .gitconfig will have those settings instead of nulls.